# Angularjs and mongodb carousel . Meanjs application

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I'm trying to make a carousel with meanjs, Carousel elements are stored in mongo, is a CRUD application that has as one of the views a carousel angularjs.
The problem in question is that carousel works only once , then remains on the last slide .

I tried to reload the view automatically with jquery but not working.

Here I give you the code:

layout.server.view.html:

```
<body class="ng-cloak">



        <div ng-include="'modules/carruselps/views/carruselp.client.view.html'"></div>
```

Client.route:

```
'use strict';

//Setting up route
angular.module('carruselps').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
        // Carruselps state routing
        $stateProvider.
        state('carruselp', {
            url: '/carrsp',
            templateUrl: 'modules/carruselps/views/carruselp.client.view.html'
        }).     
        state('listCarruselps', {
            url: '/carruselps',
            templateUrl: 'modules/carruselps/views/list-carruselps.client.view.html'
        }).
        state('createCarruselp', {
            url: '/carruselps/create',
            templateUrl: 'modules/carruselps/views/create-carruselp.client.view.html'
        }).
        state('viewCarruselp', {
            url: '/carruselps/:carruselpId',
            templateUrl: 'modules/carruselps/views/view-carruselp.client.view.html'
        }).
        state('editCarruselp', {
            url: '/carruselps/:carruselpId/edit',
            templateUrl: 'modules/carruselps/views/edit-carruselp.client.view.html'
        });
    }
]);
```

Client.controller

```
'use strict';

// Carruselps controller
angular.module('carruselps').controller('CrrslpsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Carruselps',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Carruselps) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;

        // Find a list of Carruselps

        this.slides = Carruselps.query();


    }
]);
```

Cliente.service

```
'use strict';

//Carruselps service used to communicate Carruselps REST endpoints
angular.module('carruselps').factory('Carruselps', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('carruselps/:carruselpId', { carruselpId: '@_id'
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Client.view

```
<section data-ng-controller="CrrslpsController as slidesCtrl">
     <carousel interval="5000">
      <slide ng-repeat="slide in slidesCtrl.slides" active="slide.active">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.imagen}}" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>{{slide.titulo}}</h4>
          <p>{{slide.subtitulo}}</p>
          <a class="btn btn-default"  href="{{slide.boton}}">Ver más</a>
        </div>
      </slide>
    </carousel>

</section>
```

Thanks in advance

cdm:

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos.

C:\Users\Epsilon>cd..

C:\Users>cd..

C:\>cd meanselosvendo

C:\meanselosvendo>grunt
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 66 files lint free.

Running "csslint:all" (csslint) task
Linting public/modules/apariencia/css/estilos.css...ERROR
[L1:C1]
WARNING: Outlines should only be modified using :focus. Use of outline: none or
outline: 0 should be limited to :focus rules. (outline-none) Browsers: All
[L32:C1]
>> ERROR: Expected RBRACE at line 32, col 1. This rule looks for recoverable syn
tax errors. (errors) Browsers: All
[L43:C6]
WARNING: Values of 0 shouldn't have units specified. You don't need to specify u
nits when a value is 0. (zero-units) Browsers: All
[L44:C5]
WARNING: Values of 0 shouldn't have units specified. You don't need to specify u
nits when a value is 0. (zero-units) Browsers: All
[L48:C1]
WARNING: Don't use IDs in selectors. Selectors should not contain IDs. (ids) Bro
wsers: All
[L54:C1]
WARNING: Don't use IDs in selectors. Selectors should not contain IDs. (ids) Bro
wsers: All
[L62:C1]
WARNING: Don't use IDs in selectors. Selectors should not contain IDs. (ids) Bro
wsers: All
[L74:C1]
WARNING: Don't use IDs in selectors. Selectors should not contain IDs. (ids) Bro
wsers: All
Warning: Task "csslint:all" failed. Used --force, continuing.

Running "concurrent:default" (concurrent) task
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: app/views/**/*.* gruntfile.js server.js config/**/*.js app/*
*/*.js
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
Debugger listening on port 5858
NODE_ENV is not defined! Using default development environment
MEAN.JS application started on port 3000
GET / 304 713.596 ms - -
GET /lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 304 109.931 ms - -
GET /modules/apariencia/css/estilos.css 304 101.665 ms - -
GET /lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css 304 124.894 ms - -
GET /modules/users/css/users.css 304 182.921 ms - -
GET /modules/core/css/core.css 304 198.863 ms - -
GET /lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js 304 98.869 ms - -
GET /lib/angular/angular.js 304 261.896 ms - -
GET /lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js 304 99.730 ms - -
GET /lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js 304 122.659 ms - -
GET /lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js 304 62.819 ms - -
GET /lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js 304 61.129 ms - -
GET /lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js 304 54.511 ms - -
GET /lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js 304 54.148 ms - -
GET /lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js 304 68.218 ms - -
GET /config.js 304 68.956 ms - -
GET /application.js 304 70.202 ms - -
GET /modules/apariencia/apariencia.client.module.js 304 62.755 ms - -
GET /modules/apariencia/config/apariencia.client.routes.js 304 67.864 ms - -
GET /modules/apariencia/controllers/apariencia.client.controller.js 304 70.170 m
s - -
GET /modules/carruselps/carruselps.client.module.js 304 74.529 ms - -
GET /modules/core/core.client.module.js 304 74.571 ms - -
GET /modules/users/users.client.module.js 304 75.165 ms - -
GET /modules/apariencia/services/apariencia.client.service.js 304 76.396 ms - -
GET /modules/carruselps/controllers/carruselps.client.controller.js 304 82.147 m
s - -
GET /modules/carruselps/controllers/crr.client.controller.js 304 85.169 ms - -
GET /modules/carruselps/services/carruselps.client.service.js 304 86.989 ms - -
GET /modules/carruselps/config/carruselps.client.routes.js 304 93.307 ms - -
GET /modules/core/controllers/header.client.controller.js 304 90.408 ms - -
GET /modules/core/config/core.client.routes.js 304 101.210 ms - -
GET /modules/core/controllers/home.client.controller.js 304 64.122 ms - -
GET /modules/core/services/menus.client.service.js 304 64.984 ms - -
GET /modules/users/config/users.client.config.js 304 64.989 ms - -
GET /modules/users/config/users.client.routes.js 304 64.446 ms - -
GET /modules/users/controllers/authentication.client.controller.js 304 76.634 ms
 - -
GET /modules/users/controllers/password.client.controller.js 304 73.933 ms - -
GET /modules/users/services/users.client.service.js 304 41.202 ms - -
GET /modules/users/controllers/settings.client.controller.js 304 50.162 ms - -
GET /modules/users/services/authentication.client.service.js 304 46.625 ms - -
GET /lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js 304 45.995 ms - -
GET /modules/carruselps/views/carruselp.client.view.html 304 12.826 ms - -
GET /carruselps 304 116.666 ms - -
GET /lib/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 304 17.547 ms -
 -
GET /lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css 304 133.250 ms - -
GET /lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 304 145.264 ms - -
GET /modules/apariencia/css/estilos.css 304 143.821 ms - -
GET /modules/core/css/core.css 304 145.359 ms - -
GET /modules/users/css/users.css 304 145.968 ms - -
GET /lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css.map 304 34.354 ms - -
GET /lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map 304 17.580 ms - -
```

Comment: You can't drop your whole project into a post here and just say `it's not working`. Remove all irrelevant code and provide more debugging information from both console logs in terminal for server and in browser console

Comment: I'll try for a while and I think it's best to give all the information

Comment: But you haven't provided any debugging information. Won;t get much help without specifying errors and any other troubleshooting steps that have been taken. There are far too many unknowns currently and we don't have access to your consoles

Comment: OH! Thank you. you are right

The console browser does not aparace noth

cdm:

Comment: People still codes in other language than english...